# Grouping data, later getting extra fields

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data struct:

```
Pizza
------------------
id| name
--+---------------
1 | The Best Pizza
2 | Other Pizza

Toppings
-----------------------------------------
id| pizza | order | type | requests| name        
--+-------+------------------------------
1 | 1     | 0     | A    | 10      | something
1 | 1     | 0     | A    | 14      | some
2 | 1     | 0     | B    | 12      | other
3 | 2     | 1     | A    | 40      | another
4 | 2     | 0     | A    | 20      | nononnon
```

So, my goal here is to obtain something like

```
Pizza          | Important Topping | Type    
---------------+--------------------------------------------------------     
The Best Pizza |  some             | A
The Best Pizza |  other            | B
Other Pizza    |  nononnon         | A
```

the meaning of this is:

For each group of Pizza and Topping.Type give the most important topping
where the most import topping is in the order of: Topping.order ASC, request DESC
for example, in the result above, the most important topping for "The Best Pizza" with type A is some, because both some and something toppings have the same order, but some has more requests.
for "Other Pizza", we had only one type, "nononnon" is the most import topping for it because it order is lower than "another", even another having more request

the problem that I'm facing is how to achieve this in one query or at least in a efficient way.

Now I had to pre select and oder toppings, creating temp table and ugly joins to achieve this.

Any enlightenment on how to do this?

note: this is a example of a problem that I face, I know that for a real implementation of a pizza/topping model will not be any closer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method:

```
select pizzaName, type,
       (select name from toppings t2 where t2.type = t.type and t2.pizza = t.pizza
        order by order, requests desc
        limit 1
       ) as importantTopping
from (select distinct p.name as pizzaName, type
      from toppings t join
           pizza p
           on t.pizza = p.id
     ) pt
```

It uses a correlated subquery to get the topping that you are looking for.

Comment: Gordon, as far I can see, your query will give me 5 results(one per toppings) instead of just two and I need more fields besides the name of the topping(type if we follow the example) and do one subquery for each field can be very slow. Maybe there is a way to improve?

Comment: @LucasStephanou . . . I rewrote it to make it clearer about what it is doing (I don't think it makes a difference to the results).  It is getting the distinct combinations of pizza and type, and then finding the best topping according to the rules in your question.

Comment: Gordon, it works before. I miss that 'distinct', sorry. I successfully applied the concept in my real query and it works fine, slow but works. In fact I did early something very close to this with group by and them using subqueries to get extra fields. Thank you